# How to compile VAMP Plugins to iOS ARMV7

Tags: ios, audio, boost, makefile, lapack

[VAMP](http://vamp-plugins.org/) Plugins by Queen Mary University of London is an amazing collection of BSD licensed software. All these plugins are at the basis of the [Sonic Visualizer](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/) software
[A plug Sdk](https://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/vamp-plugin-sdk) to build plugins is available as well.

You can build the plugins for OSX / Linux / Win32 targets.

Queen Mart University explain well [here](http://vamp-plugins.org/develop.html) the plugin architecture and how to build for different platforms specified above.

A Java version, jVamp is available as well. A Python wrapper also.

**But, how to build for the iOS platform ?**

So, I tried porting the Makefile to the iOS.

First I changed the file

```
build/osx/Makefile.osx
```

in this way:

```
CFLAGS := -O3 -ftree-vectorize -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch x86_64 -I../vamp-plugin-sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/ -DUSE_PTHREADS

CXXFLAGS  := $(CFLAGS)

LDFLAGS   := -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch x86_64 -lqm-dsp ../vamp-plugin-sdk/libvamp-sdk.a -framework Accelerate -lpthread -exported_symbols_list=vamp-plugin.list -install_name qm-vamp-plugins.a

PLUGIN_EXT   := .a

include build/general/Makefile.inc
```

Then build

```
macbookproloreto:qm-vamp-plugins loreto$ make -f build/osx/Makefile.osx
cc -O3 -ftree-vectorize -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch x86_64 -I../vamp-plugin-sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/ -DUSE_PTHREADS -I. -I../qm-dsp   -c -o g2cstubs.o g2cstubs.c
c++ -O3 -ftree-vectorize -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch x86_64 -I../vamp-plugin-sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/ -DUSE_PTHREADS -I. -I../qm-dsp   -c -o plugins/AdaptiveSpectrogram.o plugins/AdaptiveSpectrogram.cpp
In file included from plugins/AdaptiveSpectrogram.cpp:15:
In file included from plugins/AdaptiveSpectrogram.h:18:
In file included from ../vamp-plugin-sdk/vamp-sdk/Plugin.h:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/string:430:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:70:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:655:2: **error: Unsupported
      architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^**
```

The first issue here is that there is a unsupported architecture.

So the plugins depends on the SDK I had to build that one first:

```
cd /Users/loreto/Projects/AUDIO/VAMP/vamp-plugin-sdk
make -f build/Makefile.osx
```

Different errors occurred since I had no [OGG/VORBIS](http://www.vorbis.com/) library and no LOGG library. So I slightly modified the Makefile.osx removing these dependencies in the HOST_LIB flags. I had to keep [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) anyway:

```
HOST_LIBS       = ./libvamp-hostsdk.a -L../10.8/inst/lib -lsndfile -ldl
```

So I was able to build the static libraries here:

```
macbookproloreto:vamp-plugin-sdk loreto$ ls -l *.a
-rw-r--r--  1 loreto  staff  709840 17 Ott 23:56 libvamp-hostsdk.a
-rw-r--r--  1 loreto  staff  183720 17 Ott 23:56 libvamp-sdk.a
```

Of course these static libs are targeted to arch x86_64 so I need to add armv7 arch:

```
ARCHFLAGS = -mmacosx-version-min=$(MINVERSION) -arch x86_64 -arch armv7
```

Then make clean and compile again

```
macbookproloreto:vamp-plugin-sdk loreto$ make -f build/Makefile.osx clean
macbookproloreto:vamp-plugin-sdk loreto$ make -f build/Makefile.osx
c++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -arch x86_64 -arch armv7 -O2 -Wall -I. -I../10.8/inst/include -fPIC   -c -o src/vamp-sdk/PluginAdapter.o src/vamp-sdk/PluginAdapter.cpp
In file included from src/vamp-sdk/PluginAdapter.cpp:37:
In file included from ./vamp-sdk/PluginAdapter.h:40:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/map:64:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:68:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++config.h:41:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/os_defines.h:61:
In file included from /usr/include/unistd.h:71:
In file included from /usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:10: fatal error: 'arm/_types.h' file not found
#include "arm/_types.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/vamp-sdk/PluginAdapter.o] Error 1
```

Type definitions for arm was not found! The problem here is that the right path was

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/arm/_types.h
```

Ok let's fix this in the Makefile.osx again:

```
ARCHFLAGS = -mmacosx-version-min=$(MINVERSION) -arch armv7
CFLAGS          = $(ARCHFLAGS) -fPIC --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/
CXXFLAGS        = $(ARCHFLAGS) -O2 -Wall -I. -fPIC
CPPFLAGS        ="-pipe -no-cpp-precomp -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/" -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
```

then make the static targets:

```
make -f build/Makefile.osx sdkstatic
```

**Wow it worked! I have a vamp host sdk .a for iOS!** (I suppose to have let's say)

```
macbookproloreto:vamp-plugin-sdk loreto$ ls -l *.a
-rw-r--r--  1 loreto  staff  301176 18 Ott 00:35 libvamp-hostsdk.a
-rw-r--r--  1 loreto  staff   76024 18 Ott 00:35 libvamp-sdk.a
```

Ok but let's check with otool, since you never know:

```
macbookproloreto:vamp-plugin-sdk loreto$ otool -hv libvamp-sdk.a
Archive : libvamp-sdk.a
libvamp-sdk.a(PluginAdapter.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00      OBJECT     4       1128 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
libvamp-sdk.a(RealTime.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00      OBJECT     4       1060 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
libvamp-sdk.a(FFT.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00      OBJECT     4        584 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
libvamp-sdk.a(acsymbols.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00      OBJECT     3        500 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
```

Ok, that's the armv7 architecture.

Now, back to the plugins sdk again and change the

```
build/osx/Makefile.osx
```

as follows:

```
CFLAGS := -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/ -DUSE_PTHREADS

CXXFLAGS  := $(CFLAGS)

include build/general/Makefile.inc
```

Ok back again and make:

```
macbookproloreto:dsp loreto$ make -f build/osx/Makefile.osx
```

Boom! Another problem:

```
/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/ -DUSE_PTHREADS -I.   -c -o dsp/wavelet/Wavelet.o dsp/wavelet/Wavelet.cpp
cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/ -DUSE_PTHREADS -I.   -c -o hmm/hmm.o hmm/hmm.c
hmm/hmm.c:21:10: fatal error: 'clapack.h' file not found
#include <clapack.h>            /* LAPACK for matrix inversion */
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [hmm/hmm.o] Error 1
macbookproloreto:dsp loreto$ vi build/osx/Makefile.osx
```

LAPACK not found.

But as for Apple Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iPhone40APIDiffs/), Apple introduced LAPACK in the Accelerate.frameworks since iOS4.0!

In fact clapack.h is here:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/clapack.h

So let's add this somewhere in the ../dsp/build/Makefile.osx

```
CFLAGS := -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/ -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/ -DUSE_PTHREADS
```

And now let's make it again, but let me check the arch:

```
macbookproloreto:dsp loreto$ otool -hv libqm-dsp.a 
Archive : libqm-dsp.a
libqm-dsp.a(Pitch.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00      OBJECT     4        516 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
libqm-dsp.a(Chromagram.o):
Mach header
```

Sound good! One level back in the plugins folder now and make

```
In file included from plugins/AdaptiveSpectrogram.cpp:15:
plugins/AdaptiveSpectrogram.h:22:10: fatal error: 'dsp/transforms/FFT.h' file not found
#include <dsp/transforms/FFT.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Uhm ok the dsp/ misses the tranforms folder  - gosh!

Another error:

```
clang: error: invalid argument '-install_name qm-vamp-plugins.a' only allowed with '-dynamiclib'
make: *** [qm-vamp-plugins.a] Error 1
```

Let's fix again the Makefile.osx:

```
CFLAGS := -O3 -ftree-vectorize -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch armv7 -I../vamp-plugin-sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/ -DUSE_PTHREADS

CXXFLAGS  := $(CFLAGS)

LDFLAGS   := -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch armv7 -lqm-dsp ../vamp-plugin-sdk/libvamp-sdk.a -framework Accelerate -lpthread
```

Ok, now the error is architecture undefined symbol errors: to long look at the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/7034060)
like:

```
  "std::cerr", referenced from:
  "typeinfo for std::istream", referenced from:
  "std::ostream::put(char)""
  std::ostream::operator<<(int)",
```

This reminds me to the [boost](http://www.boost.org/) C++ libraries!

So I need to get boost, compile for iOS then include it in the Makefile and it should work, isn't it ? This could take long...

So do this by now

```
macbookproloreto:vamp-plugin-sdk loreto$ echo $'\360\237\215\272'
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff3kp.png]

After getting boost as iOS framework distribution from [here](https://github.com/FWKamil/boost-ios) and adding

-I/Users/loreto/Projects/AUDIO/LIBS/boost-ios/Dist/boost.framework/Headers/

I have the same error...uhm I suppose I'm missing the standard C++ library here!

```
macbookproloreto:Headers loreto$ locate libc++.dylib | grep iPhoneOS7.0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.dylib
```

bingo!

So

```
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.dylib
```

Error again (doh) !

Tried with no success

```
    -I/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib
   -lstdc++
```

Stucked on a very simple linking issue.

Again.

```
macbookproloreto:vamp-plugin-sdk loreto$ echo $'\360\237\215\272'
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff3kp.png]

The most interesting part of the error is the first static library being compiled:

```
make -f build/osx/Makefile.osx

c++ -o qm-vamp-plugins.a g2cstubs.o plugins/AdaptiveSpectrogram.o plugins/BarBeatTrack.o plugins/BeatTrack.o plugins/DWT.o plugins/OnsetDetect.o plugins/ChromagramPlugin.o plugins/ConstantQSpectrogram.o plugins/KeyDetect.o plugins/MFCCPlugin.o plugins/SegmenterPlugin.o plugins/SimilarityPlugin.o plugins/TonalChangeDetect.o plugins/Transcription.o libmain.o -L../qm-dsp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -arch armv7 -lqm-dsp ../vamp-plugin-sdk/libvamp-sdk.a -framework Accelerate -lpthread
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const", referenced from:
      _VampPlugin::Vamp::RealTime::toString() const in libvamp-sdk.a(RealTime.o)
      _VampPlugin::Vamp::RealTime::toText(bool) const in libvamp-sdk.a(RealTime.o)
  "std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const", referenced from:
      _VampPlugin::Vamp::PluginAdapterBase::Impl::getDescriptor() in libvamp-sdk.a(PluginAdapter.o)
```

Here we can see that one of the static library compiled does not contain the right architecture.

I have two static libraries here:

```
lqm-dsp ../vamp-plugin-sdk/libvamp-sdk.a
```

If I run otool on that I can see that the cpu time is ARM7 for both of them:

```
macbookproloreto:qm-vamp-plugins loreto$ otool -hv ../vamp-plugin-sdk/libvamp-sdk.a
Archive : ../vamp-plugin-sdk/libvamp-sdk.a
../vamp-plugin-sdk/libvamp-sdk.a(PluginAdapter.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00      OBJECT     4       1128 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
```

So what's the matter with Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.dylib ?

Comment: Any chance you can please put the iOS library online if you successfully created it?

Comment: Yes! As soon as I have everything working I will put online in the next days. I'm going to have armv7 and armv7s.

Comment: Any luck with getting it working?

Comment: I've got a little side project that I would love to add key detection to, any luck? Thanks for posting what you got so far.

Answer (score 2):

Try commenting in the code the usage of the standard libraries.

It's probably only used for debug.